# Can a Facebook app, change profile security settings?

Tags: facebook, security, privacy

I was curious about creating a Facebook app, that can be used to help a user lock down their privacy and security settings, but I'm not sure its even possible. Can anyone let me know if its possible?

thanks for any advice or suggestions!

Comment: what do you mean by lock down their privacy and security system?

Comment: Of course it is.  If you get the user to agree to it.  However, if you can lock it down you can surely unlock it.